# What's the name of the mission in CoD4 where you get strafed by the MiG?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I remember a mission in CoD4 where you and your squad are making your way along a road and a MiG finds you. I remember the jet flies overhead a few times inverted and the pilot sees you and then starts strafing you. I remember it being really awesome and I want to find a video of it on Youtube but I can't remember what it is called.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're thinking of Battlefield 3 instead of Call of Duty 4.

[Battlefield 3 - Jet/stinger scene (Campo, Matkovic death)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVXPT-SeJXI&ab_channel=LDinos)

The closest scene to what you described in Call of Duty 4 involves a helicopter instead of a jet, and it's during the game's final mission.